# How can I open a text file with Notepad?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

Hoping somebody can help me with the following.
The function works just fine:

```
def fileOpen(filename, accessmode):
    file = open(filename, accessmode)
    for line in file:
        print(line)
    return
```

The `filename` is "open.txt"

Instead of opening notepad the results are displayed in the python console. Notepad is not opened. I know that it can be solved with this:

```
import os
os.system('notepad.exe ' + 'open.txt')
```

But I was wondering if there is a setting in visual studio to get around my problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

VisualStudio Community 2017
Python 3.6.6

Sparkington

Comment: So you want the `print` function to open notepad instead of **printing** it to the console? (which is its job)
what's wrong with `os.system('notepad.exe' + 'open.txt')` ?

Comment: Hi there, what exactly you're trying to accomplish with this script? Right now you're reading the file and printing it's contents into console.

Comment: There's no problem in this code. `open` is meant to open a file, not *execute* it

Comment: why would you expect calling `open()` to launch an arbitrary Windows text editor?  It creates a file handle (opens the file for read or write access)

Comment: A small checklist for a question: 1) here is what I want to achieve, 2) here is what I tried, 3) here is what is wrong. As of now, the question reads "I was able to print my file to console, notepad.exe does not open, what is wrong with  VisualStudio setting?"

Answer (score 1):

The 'problem' is that there is no problem. You are attempting to use the print function to open notepad, not to print to the console - which is its **job**. This is 'solved' by using `os.system()` which will execute the notepad.exe program with the argument of 'open.txt'.

So I think you do not need to be looking for a solution to this problem, as there is no problem to be honest with you. You are using `print` to do something which is not its intended purpose, or even close to it. So is there any wonder that it doesn't work?

My suggestion to you, is to just use `os.system` and not to try using `print` for something other than its function.

Comment: Thanks John, a well formulated and substantiated answer. as you can read I am new to all this. I will be more careful in the future with my questions. Judging by  the responses its easier to point out that somebody is wrong than to be constructive

Comment: That is good to hear. I tried to not just tell you that you are doing something wrong, but to tell you why and be constructive, so I hope you are satisfied with the answer and you will either use os.system or an equivalent method.

Comment: I followed a microsoft MVA python course and every time they used open or print for a file it "miraculously" opened the appropriate file in notepad, excel etc and no mention of and certainly not visible an os import or os.system. So I naively assumed that there was some sort of file Association going on.  Thanks again

Comment: That seems more understandable now, thanks for clarifying and although that may be so, it is certainly not normal behavior for print. You are welcome for the help, I am glad I could resolve your problem, if not in the intended way.

Comment: Also, did you mean to spell your username "Sparkington" or "Spakington"? Because your username is "Spakington" and in the post it is "Sparkington". As well, not to be demanding or anything, but if you accept this answer could you please mark this answer as accepted.